# toggle button with validation

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

I'm building an application where power needs to be set on or off via a web browser. I have a toggle button working but at "off", I would like some  validation. The toggle button is created through a checkbox method.

How can I add validation that if user clicks "OK", the power goes off, but on "Cancel", checkbox should not be unchecked?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var X = 0;

  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    X = 1;
    alert("power on " + X); // only for test
  };

  if (checkBox.checked == false) {
    //     alert("power off" );
    return confirm("This will shutdown power!. Are you sure?")

    if ($(X = 1))
      return true;
    //      ('.myCheck').prop('unchecked')
    //       ('#switch-input').prop('checked', true);
    //       $(checkBox.prop('checked', true);
    else
      return false;
  };

}
```

```css
/* Toggle switch Flat
==========================*/

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #eceeef;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before,
.switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  -o-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before {
  content: attr(data-off);
  right: 11px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.switch-label:after {
  content: attr(data-on);
  left: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label {
  background: #E1B42B;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-handle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-handle {
  left: 74px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}


/* Switch Flat
==========================*/

.switch-flat {
  padding: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  background-image: none;
}

.switch-flat .switch-label {
  background: #FFF;
  border: solid 2px #eceeef;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-flat .switch-label:after {
  color: #0088cc;
}

.switch-flat .switch-handle {
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  background: #dadada;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-flat .switch-handle:before {
  background: #eceeef;
}

.switch-flat .switch-input:checked~.switch-label {
  background: #FFF;
  border-color: #0088cc;
}

.switch-flat .switch-input:checked~.switch-handle {
  left: 72px;
  background: #0088cc;
  box-shadow: none;
}


/* Transition
============================================================ */

.switch-label,
.switch-handle {
  transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title> My Toggle Demo</title>
  <!--link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"-->
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Toggle Button Example</h2>
  <label class="switch switch-flat">
 <input  class="switch-input" type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()" />
 <span class="switch-label" data-on="Power On" data-off="Power Off"></span> 
    <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
  </label>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `if ($(X = 1))` doesn't make sense.  What are you trying to do there?

Comment: nothing will run after `return confirm("This will shutdown power!. Are you sure?")` so save the answer instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because when the event handler runs the checkbox has already been unchecked, hence when you `return false` it's too late. To fix this you can simply check what the outcome of `confirm()` was, and if the user cancelled the operation, simply set the checkbox back to a `checked` state.

There's a couple of other things to note. Firstly, the handling of your `X` variable makes little sense. I've removed that logic from the answer as it's irrelevant to the problem. Secondly, you should avoid using `on*` event attributes. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead.

```js
document.getElementById("myCheck").addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (this.checked) {
    console.log("power on");
  } else {
    if (!confirm("This will shutdown power! Are you sure?")) {
      this.checked = true;
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF 25px);
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px white, inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: inherit;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #eceeef;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), inset 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before,
.switch-label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -.5em;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-transition: inherit;
  -moz-transition: inherit;
  -o-transition: inherit;
  transition: inherit;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.switch-label:before {
  content: attr(data-off);
  right: 11px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.switch-label:after {
  content: attr(data-on);
  left: 11px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label {
  background: #E1B42B;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15), inset 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.switch-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 40%, #f0f0f0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-handle:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -6px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #FFFFFF);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
}

.switch-input:checked~.switch-handle {
  left: 74px;
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.switch-flat {
  padding: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  background-image: none;
}

.switch-flat .switch-label {
  background: #FFF;
  border: solid 2px #eceeef;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-flat .switch-label:after {
  color: #0088cc;
}

.switch-flat .switch-handle {
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  background: #dadada;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-flat .switch-handle:before {
  background: #eceeef;
}

.switch-flat .switch-input:checked~.switch-label {
  background: #FFF;
  border-color: #0088cc;
}

.switch-flat .switch-input:checked~.switch-handle {
  left: 72px;
  background: #0088cc;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-label,
.switch-handle {
  transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: All 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: All 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Toggle Button Example</h2>
<label class="switch switch-flat">
  <input  class="switch-input" type="checkbox" id="myCheck" />
  <span class="switch-label" data-on="Power On" data-off="Power Off"></span> 
  <span class="switch-handle"></span> 
</label>
```

Comment: Hi Rory,  Thank you for the suggestions, applied your modifications and now it's working as I wanted.